# Are Unicoins April's Fool Prank?

Tags: support

I have just tried a power using Unicoins. And, it's working. I have just adopted star-trek tag to show my Avatar (it's working at least from my account). All other powers seem legit except *Guaranteed Answer*. So, it must be prank.

I need confirmation.

Comment: I literally have ZERO clue what you're talking about.

Comment: @phantom42 Oh then, looks like you haven't got April 1 in your time zone. Be ready to use awesome powers like Marquee question titles and tag adoption. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it's not April in my timezone.

Comment: @Richard See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227355/havent-got-100-unicoins-on-stack-overflow-yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

Unicorns have been discovered. They *do* have magical powers. The powers that be have decided to reward us with their "coins".

Comment: And the unicorns [can be harvested for meat](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e5a7/).

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed...

Whenever I go to buy Unicoins using real money, there happens a technical difficulty. And, I can get Unicoins for free by hammering rocks. :)

Comment: I totally missed getting free unicorns from hammering rocks.  Never imagined the concept, is this borrowed from some universe I have not read?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Probably, but I am not aware of any. Please, ask it on the main site.